# Is R's `base::factorial` memoised?

Tags: r, recursion

(I'm going to look this up in a second, but I want the answer posted on SO so google finds it and the next person doesn't have to page through the [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source).)

Recursive functions are known to be slow when they call themselves many times. One solution to this is to write previous answers to memory so they can be reused when the cost of recomputing is less than the cost of writing and reading back.

R's `factorial` calls R's `gamma`, and `gamma` calls an R `.Primitive`. Is that primitive memoised?

Comment: Everything you say here is correct, but it suggests that `base::factorial`'s implementation is recursive, which (I think) it's not.  It *might* be more efficient for R to do some looping or (memoised) recursion to compute factorials for small values of `n`, but in fact all it does is to call the Gamma function.

Comment: PS it might make a fun Rcpp exercise to figure out the break-even point for the relative speeds of these three approaches (looping, memoised recursion, Gamma call).

Comment: @BenBolker you're right, it's not recursive either. There's another question about prod(1:30) vs factorial(30) and from my glance at the source, it's a Chebyshev polynomial for small values and Stirling approx for large.

Answer (score 5):

Of course not because if it were we'd know that R has *native* memoization support.  Which it does not.  Hence...

It is however cheap to do after the fact as I discuss eg in the intro chapter of the Rcpp book because our *"Hello, world!"* really is the Fibonacci sequence ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. Looking at https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/gamma.c (assuming that's what `.Primitive("gamma")` finds), it looks like `gammafn` uses a Chebyshev polynomial to find `gamma` for inputs with a floating-point absolute value < 10, and returns

```
exp((y - 0.5) * log(y) - y + M_LN_SQRT_2PI +
            ((2*y == (int)2*y)? stirlerr(y) : lgammacor(y)))
```

for larger inputs. I may not be understanding this correctly, but I don't see any memoisation.

---

Ben Bolker points out that this is not recursive either. And I should add that the large number switch is using Stirling's approximation. This was all inherited from FORTRAN code written at a famous lab. I suppose I should pose a follow-up question as to why these approximations to the gamma function are preferable to more accurate versions in statistical applications. Maybe because MCMC makes so many calls to the beta distribution for common priors?

Comment: yea, looks like a simple `for` loop

Comment: @A.Webb Can you enlighten me? I'm looking at https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/gamma.c#L182 .

Comment: @A.Webb Ah ok, I missed the "else" condition on https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/gamma.c#L198.

Comment: @Gregor you might be looking at the float version, for factorial look at when it is integer https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/gamma.c#L194

Comment: @nongkrong Ah, yes indeed. Thanks!